# My code from only one file disappears after some merge requests, why?

Tags: git, gitlab

I had the strangest thing happened to me today. A series of merge request totally erase my code, along with the commit, in one file only. Our current git flow is like this:

- We have the "master" branch for production code
- We have the "develop" branch, based from master, for testing
- We have feature branches, based from master. After coding we merge feature branches into develop for testing
- In order to resolve conflict, I have to create another branch, based from develop. Let's call this branch "my_develop". I merge my feature branch code into this branch, resolve conflict, and then create merge request from this branch to develop.

Today this is what we did:

1. I and another developer (we only have two developers in frontend team), create two feature branches, let called them "my_feature_branch" and "his_feature_branch".
2. After coding, I merge my_feature_branch into my_develop, and create a merge request to develop. And this merge request was merged.
3. After that, the other developer finished his coding, merged branch master into his_feature_branch to get the latest code, and create merge request from his_feature_branch to develop. This merge request was merged.

After merging his merge request, some code changes from my merge request disappears. I checked every commits after the merge commit from my_develop to develop, but cannot find the commit where my code is deleted. Even stranger, only code from one file disappears, while other files are fine.

I check the history of the file that has code disappeared. There's no commit from my merge request. It's like my changes for that file has never ever existed.

When I create another merge request from my_develop to develop, gitlab says there're no commits to compare, even though the code on two branches are different.

I don't know what happens here. Can someone explain to me why this happen, and how can I fix it?

Comment: "We have feature branches, based from master. After coding we merge feature branches into develop for testing" Ok, so that's wrong and you should stop doing that. Basing a feature branch from master and merging it into develop is a good way to wind up in trouble.

Comment: "I check the history of the file that has code disappeared" Really? How? Did you use `log` with the name of the file? Do you know about _history simplification?_ Don't talk in generalities; show us the _actual commands_ you gave and what Git _actually said_ in response.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but having branches called `develop` and `master` is a standard naming convention for the Git Flow branching strategy, but you are not using that. What you are using is similar to a strategy called Gitworkflows (what the maintainers of Git use), and in that case I would consider renaming your `develop` branch to `next`, which is an integration branch for testing the *next* features that will end up in `master`. Also, `next` branch should typically be reset back to `master` every once in a while, to get rid of all the "garbage" that didn't make the cut into `master`.

Comment: I suspect iamdhavalparmar's answer is correct for *why* this happened (mistake made during merge conflict resolution). To prove it, you can use `git log --first-parent` and compare the recent commits in that list with the previous ones, to see which merge removed your changes. From there the changes are either in a commit brought in from that merge, or the merge commit itself (most likely).

Comment: @matt Yes. This work flow is causing me headache, and I'm planning to change that. About the file, when I use git log "my_file", I can see a log of commits, but not the commit where I add my code. I also checked on Gitlab (select the file and click "History" button, same result. I'm sure that code is on develop once, because I tested it after my merge request was merge. I still see the changes in that file in the merge commit from my_develop to develop, but when checking every commit after that (on develop), I don't see the commit where the code is removed.

Comment: What I'm telling you is that `git log "my_file"` omits some commits, which is probably why you are not seeing the commit you expect to see.

Answer (score 1):

It may happen because your friend had also worked on the file same file as yours

- First, you merged to the Repo, So the files are changed now in
  GitHub according to your files.
- Then Your friend made a PR in the same Repo which again causes the Main
  branch to change its code according to your friend's PR

When you get any PR you should check if there is any **merge conflict** which dictates if any two files have changed in the PR so you can choose according to which files code you want to keep.

For now I think you can Rollback.

Comment: The commit where I add my code is still there, and when I look at changes I can still see where I add the code. But every commit after that does not contain the part where the code is removed. If the problem is because of resolving conflict, shouldn't I see in the changes history the part where my code is removed? I check changes on Gitlab.

Comment: I think you need to post the link of your GitHub Repo also, So everybody who will come to this question can actually see the problem in your Repo too.

Comment: I would do that if I could, but this is a private repo of my company, so I can only describe it by words.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you made changes and merged to develop, and your colleague did not pull the changes which you made to develop.

> After that, the other developer finished his coding, merged branch master into his_feature_branch to get the latest code, and create merge request from his_feature_branch to develop. This merge request was merged.

You merged into develop, however he pulled from master, and never got your changes. When he merged to develop, merge thought he was removing your changes.

We all need to remember that merge does not know our intent, and sometime does not do what we expect. In this case, it could not know that the process followed was flawed.